# Color issues using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm experiencing issues setting a background color in PHPExcel.

I have done this many many times and am wondering if this is a bug in PHPExcel itself.

The code I use is

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D17')->getFill()
->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID) ->getStartColor()->setRGB('ff0000');
```

I am trying to set the following hex colour a87ac6 this is a shade of purple, when i put this code in

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D17')
->getFill() ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
->getStartColor()->setRGB('A87ac6');
```

The cell is actually showing up grey rather than purple.

Could someone advise?

Comment: I have tested your piece of code and it is displaying the cell purple. Could you check if you are not re-filling it grey in the further part of your script?

Comment: @GrzegorzPawlik This is my only line concerning color for this whole worksheet

Comment: That's strange... Have you maybe tried to write the color with consistent capitalization like 'A87AC6' or 'a87ac6'?

Comment: @GrzegorzPawlik I have indeed, very very baffled by this.

Comment: Could you write which version of Excel and OS are you using?

Comment: Ah, I was using 2008 for mac, having tested it on a windows machine it is displaying the correct colour, I guess I will submit it as a bug on the developers site

Comment: Sadly, I suspect that the developer will be able to do very little about a limitation in a specific version of MS Excel for mac, other than remembering the problem if anybody ever reports it in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, apparently it is not related with PHPExcel but with this specific version of Excel (2008) on Mac. It recognizes just the colors from its palette which by default is limiting them to about 50-60 colors. Updating Excel version will fix the issue.

Comment: much appreciated on the assist there.